# No GUI on Lenovo with nvidia

Tags: nvidia, lenovo

I updated my Ubuntu with the normal update on December 17th, and now I have no GUI display.

It is an Lenovo 4314-9VG S/N R9-69 PE7 10/08, with 3.2.0-57-generic-pae kernel

Have tried to make `sudo apt-get...` install different nvidia things.

First I tried to reestablish xorg.conf with nvidia-xconfig.

Nothing has so far helped.

The first line in the xorg.conf says

```
version 304.108 buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-07)
```

Comment: Are you stuck at [tty](http://img.scoop.it/fQJBWDXZz4N-iAiZto85CTl72eJkfbmt4t8yenImKBVvK0kTmF0xjctABnaLJIm9)? Try `startx`.

Answer (score 0):

To revert to a previous proprietary Nvidia driver version we will have to remove the "updates" driver from the command line.

If we can't see a terminal we can open TTY1 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>. In the terminal we log in with an administrator user and password (nothing shown on typing).

Then we can purge the *"updates"* driver and reboot with

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current-updates nvidia-304-updates
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current ## only if not present
sudo reboot
```

This should bring us the graphical desktop back.